# Time a GPIO input

Tags: gpio, python

I want to time the duration a input GPIO pin is HIGH with microsecond precision.

I tried while loop with `time.time()` , but it adds a lot of rogue delays.

How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: `python` and `microsecond` do not usually belong to the same sentence =) you'd better think about using C/C++ instead.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be best implementing this in a C library, it could be trivially done with WiringPi and then wrapped in a Python wrapper to return the number of microseconds. I'd suggest a function prototype of:

```
timePin(GPIO_PIN,HIGH/LOW,TIMEOUT)
```

Where `GPIO_PIN` is the input we're watching, `HIGH/LOW` is the state we want to time, and `TIMEOUT` is the number of millis or micros we would want to wait before returning a failure code- or the C call could hang your Python script indefinitely.

At the moment the waitForInterrupt function in wiringPi, and subsequently wiringPi2-Python, is a lot like this, it returns the result of a poll() call which ( although I'm not sure ) could very well be the number of milliseconds or microseconds it has waited.

Unfortunately waitForInterrupt doesn't necessarily time how long the pin is in a specific state, but just when the next state change is. But it's close!

Out of interest, why are you attempting to time the input? I can certainly think of reasons to do so ( infra-red signals spring immediately to mind! ).

Comment: I didn't know there was a wiringpi 2... let me try it out... and I am doing ultrasound... :)

Comment: I couldn't find waitForInterrupt() in python wiringpi2, only in C.

Comment: I time the input to determine what letter is trasmitted; I'm working on a project to make raspberry pies communicate.

Answer (score 0):

It is doable in Python without C. You will get down to 10us approx on the B+ model with tight code. Use wiringpi.micros() -- documented only in C, but available in python (undocumented). I use it all the time in complex code. For wiringpi, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wiringpi2 -- and beginners install guide, see http://raspi.tv/how-to-install-wiringpi2-for-python-on-the-raspberry-pi#install .. This is an example of it's general use in Python..

```
import wiringpi2
for n1 in range(1,10): print wiringpi2.micros()
```